# Mystery behind silent letters

Tags: speech, rules

I have doubts about words in the English language that have a silent letter.
So I want to know how to understand whether a letter is silent or not.

Comment: The only sure way is to check a dictionary. There are other rules-of-thumb that are accurate most of the time, but not all of the time. However, these are very complicated, so it's not possible to explain them all in a single post here. Can you make your question more specific?

Comment: Can you give us some examples?

Comment: W is silent in words like write,  wrong etc. K is silent  in knife, knight.  I'm sure there are detailed studies about silent letters, but I haven't seen one. Perhaps I find something.

Comment: In some cases, the silent letters used to be pronounced. I think "knife" is an example. However, in some cases silent letters were actually deliberately added to English words in a misguided attempt to bring the spelling closer to Latin. I think "debt" is an example (in French the word is *dette*).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you google for silent letters in English you find quite a lot of websites, eg this one
http://mws.ust.hk/sir/silent_words.php

One typical case are words with clusters of three consonants. English has a tendency to simplify three consonants by dropping the consonant in the middle for ease of articulation as in

to listen /lisn/, to soften /sofn/, muscle /masl/, subtle /satl/ (IPA simplified).